# Bootstrap nav-tabs , list of open tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a list of tabs created using bootstrap and looking for how we can pull the list of open tabs titles using jQuery. Appreciate any helps.

Below is the Full HTML
.............................................................................

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="Sortable.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
        #tab-list .close{
            margin-left: 7px;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var tabID = 1;
                $('#btn-add-tab').click(function () {
                    tabID++;
                    $('#tab-list').append($('<li><a href="#tab' + tabID + '" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab ' + tabID + '<button class="close" type="button" title="Remove this page">Ã—</button></a></li>'));
                    $('#tab-content').append($('<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab' + tabID + '">Tab '+ tabID +' content </div>'));
                });

                $('#btn-show-tabs').click(function () {
                    alert('Tabs');
                });


                $('#tab-list').on('click','.close',function(){
                    var tabID = $(this).parents('a').attr('href');
                    $(this).parents('li').remove();
                    $(tabID).remove();

                    //display first tab
                    var tabFirst = $('#tab-list a:first');
                    tabFirst.tab('show');
                });

                var list = document.getElementById("tab-list");
                new Sortable(list);
            });
            </script>
    </head>

    <body>
            <!-- Container Start -->
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Main Content Area Start -->
                <div class="main-container">
                    <!---  --->
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p>
                                    <button id="btn-add-tab" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Tab</button> &nbsp
                                    <button id="btn-show-tabs" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Show Tabs</button><br>
                                </p>
                                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                                <ul id="tab-list" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
                                </ul>

                                <!-- Tab panes -->
                                <div id="tab-content" class="tab-content">
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
                                            Tab 1 content
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!---  --->
                </div>
                <!-- Main Content Area End -->
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Container End -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will have only one tab open at a time! 'list of open tabs' sounds buggy.

Comment: Provide what you have tried. jquery and full html

Comment: Hi, I didn't mean list of active tabs, I am looking for list of all tabs. From above sample code I am looking for a list like 'tab1,tab2'

Comment: @JeroenHeier's suggestion would help I suppose.

Comment: Just updated the post with full HTML, on click on "Show Tabs" button I need the list of tabs to be displayed.